# PHP ignoring my date.timezone?

Tags: php, apache, datetime, timezone

`time()` keeps producing the same timestamp , even though in my php.ini I keep toggling between

`date.timezone = "Asia/Irkutsk"`

and

`date.timezone = "Europe/Belgrade"`

phpinfo():

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2012.3
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Asia/Irkutsk 

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2012.3
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Belgrade
```

Timestamps stays the same. Howcome?

Comment: Do you have your time right on your local pc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the wrong assumption.

Unix timestamps are always in UTC. No exception.
Changing the timezone does not change the exact moment of the epoch (1st of january, 1970), so the number of seconds since then will always be 'correct'.

Comment: makes sense. It's weird though, I'm trying to produce local timestamp with `Zend_Date::now()` and in resources it looks as though it gives a local one.. when it doesn't

Comment: There's not really such a thing as a local timestamp though. I think you need to re-think what you actually need to achieve, and then ask how you can do so.

Comment: well I'm just trying to sync between my mysql now() and php time(). mysql is picking up system time. I'll just set up mysql to use UTC :)

Comment: Even better: use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in mysql and don't be timezone dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart PHP after making changes in php.ini

Comment: If I hadn't restarted it, changes wouldn't be visible in php.ini, and they obviously are :)

Comment: it would be visible on php.ini but it would not be loaded in php, well sorry for that, I thought it was a straight forward one, guess it is because of what Evert said.

Comment: I meant phpinfo(), not php.ini, in my first comment, pardon

Comment: no probs, to be honest though a -1 for an answer which could have been a solution is harsh :D

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and spoke to my host, they explained that any timezone setting in php.ini is ignored and that the .htaccess file must be changed as follows;

Add this to .htaccess

```
php_value date.timezone "Europe/London"
```

Then display using

```
echo date('d-m-Y H:i');
```